# Mantener alto de Background image a toda la pantalla en Portrait y Landscape

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una imagen de fondo en un elemento que esta a 100% height y width.

**CSS**

```
#splash{
    background-image: url("../img/background_splash.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <body>
     <section id="splash">
         //contenido
     </section>
 </body>
```

Probe usando `vh` y `vmax` pero no logre nada.

Funciona todo bien en todas las resoluciones, menos cuando me voy a `landscape` desde el celular. Es decir, el alto no llega a ocupar toda la pantalla si no hasta donde se renderizó la primera vez en Portrait. Como el contenido sobrepasa la pantalla, tengo que hacer scroll y cuando hago scroll se ve el blanco debajo.

¿Alguna idea?

Desde ya agradezco el interés.

Comment: Adjunta código para poder entender

Comment: hola, ahí esta bien?

Comment: bien, tienes el html adicionalmente?

Comment: ahi agregue el codigo

Comment: honestamente no entiendo la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

bueno puedo resolverlo y dejo acá el código por si a alguien le sirve, el truco es usar

```
vmax
```

en el elemento hijo, una imagen mas chica para mobile y ademas

```
100% height
```

en los elementos padre

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
#splash, .background-body {
background-image: url(../img/background_splash_mobile.jpg);
height: 100vmax !important;
}}
```